# Visual C++ 2015 generates no leading "_"

Tags: c++, dllexport, name-decoration

I'm creating dlls now for a long time, but I'm a bit curious about a problem which arised in my new project, the first one with `VS C++ 2015`.

Its nothing special, a simple C++ project, creating a windows 32/64 Bit dll.
I'm exporting my functions as "C" like this (no DEF file):

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) foo();
```

But my application loading the dll fails with `Can not find _foo()`. Checking the dll with the Dependency Walker shows me `foo()` is exported, but without the obligatory leading `_`.

I can not find a compiler/linker option having an effect in the creation of the exported function names.

Comment: you're trying to export functions as [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) without actually marking them as such. This can lead to stack corruption

Comment: Check `#pragma comment (linker, "/EXPORT:...")`, e.g. here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx

Comment: @MadScientist the OP is better off ensuring their function is exported with the right calling convention, `__stdcall` is prefixed with an `_` failing to use the proper convention can and will lead to stack corruption and undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks this solved defenitely a port of my problem. My earlier compiler (Embarcadero seems to do it also without "__stdcall").

Comment: Now my statements look like this:

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall foo();

In dependency walker I can see now "_foo@0", so I have my missing "_", but why "@0" which is the byte length of the paramters (here none), as I think? Embarcadero simply created "_foo" with the same source.

Comment: `@0` is the offset ordinal into the exported names table and is not actually part of the name.  fyi you can import by ordinal or by name.

Comment: Ok, so my problem should be solved. Great thanks to you all!